# There is some way to tell javadoc not copied the descriptopn of methods from base class?

Tags: javadoc

I have an abstract class and a couple of sub-classes that extended it.
Every method has another description.
But, the javadoc displays me the same description for all of them,
with this message

```
Description copied from class:"XXX"
```

"XXX" - the name of the class.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: You got the Javadoc format wrong in the derived classes, so it wasn't found as Javadoc.

Comment: Do i need to generate every edit i made a new javadoc ?
Its no updating automatically ?

Comment: Javadocs generator creates static pages for you, you just have to rerun it. Just like compiling your code, when you make a change, you have to recompile your code to reflect the new change

Comment: Ok. How do i do this ?
I just generated it by Project---Generate Javadoc...

Comment: That's correct. If it still doesn't work, post an example that isn't being seen. And check that you're looking at the current Javadoc, not something old.